# Transfer Function of Circuit with Transformer

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, transfer-function

I am trying to confirm the results for the transfer function of the circuit shown below. However, I don't seem to get any near the given solution. My main question is if someone knows how is the transformer considered (accounted for) in this analysis? Also, I would appreciate if someone can direct to the solution or setting up the main equations for the mesh analysis.
[image: Given circuit]

[image: Given solution for Transfer Function of above circuit]

The author gives some directions on how to approach the analysis: "When analyzing the power link in Figure 3, the source of the uplink can be considered as a short circuit. By leveraging the mesh-current technique [22], the voltage and current transfer functions of the power link are derived as shown in Equations (1) and (2), where M=k(LoLi)^0.5 is the mutual inductance between the coils and s is the Laplacian. Equations (1) and (2) will be used to calculate the PTE in Section 4.1.3. The relation between Vo(s) and Vload(s) is denoted in Equation (3). Equation (3) will be used to calculate the power carrier amplitude on the out-body coil in Section 4.1.1."

Thanks for the help!

Note: This is an open access paper titled "An NFC on Two-Coil WPT Link for Implantable Biomedical Sensors under Ultra-Weak Coupling" and all the credit goes to the authors: Cheng Gong, et. al.

Comment: Save yourself all the bother and use a simulation package. Then, not only can you check the equations but you can make amendments and add in MOSFETs and diode rectifiers etc..

Comment: To solve this transfer function (TF), I recommend to replace the transformer by a model featuring a turns ratio \$1:N\$ and a leakage term representative of the coupling coefficient \$k\$. \$M\$ and \$k\$ are linked by \$M=k\sqrt{L_1L_2}\$. This way, you can either reflect sec side elements to the primary side or prim side to the sec side, all scaled by the turns ratio squared. The TF should become easier to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some significant progress towards solving or proving these TF (although it is quite lengthy). To model the transformer the following S-Model is used:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVUu7a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V1 = s I1 L1 + sM I2
V2 = s I2 L2 + sM I1
After that a lengthy and convoluted process begins (sorry for the terrible formatting).